# How can I convert PostCSS into valid CSS code?

Tags: css, postcss

I'm following a course on `Udemy` ([GIT Workflow](https://www.udemy.com/git-a-web-developer-job-mastering-the-modern-workflow/)) about Web Development. It include `Gulp` for automation and used `PostCSS` instead of `Sass`.

My code editor is `VSCode`. I install from `VSCode` Market to support `PostCSS` (.pcss) . [PostCSS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpylua.language-postcss) . The problem is, I don't know how to compile .pcss to css.

1. How can I convert `PostCSS` to valid `CSS` with `Gulp`? OR
2. On `Sass`, I can easily compile it with `node-sass` and watch it. 
   **Is there any equivalent of `PostCSS` ?** (i.e node-postcss)

P.S - In my `CSS` file, I write my `postCSS` styling. I get many warning regarding with the syntax. I can compile it with gulp, but it does not get right with `mixins`.